# "Missing required prop" when trying to pass prop to my Hello World component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I am trying to integrate Vue 3 with our CMS, which also has a Vue 2.6 project running side by side.

I have been able to create a sample widget in our CMS that is rendering my HelloWorld component correctly. However, when I try to pass a prop to that component, the component doesn't seem to be receiving the prop and is not rendered.
The console shows the error `Missing required prop: "msg" at <HelloWorld>`.

My view code looks like this:

```
<wvd-hello-world msg="Hello World, coming to you from a Vue 3 component" />
```

My component:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
defineProps<{
  msg: string
}>()
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <h1 class="green">{{ msg }}</h1>
  </div>
</template>
```

And my `main.ts`:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue'

createApp(HelloWorld).mount("wvd-hello-world");
```

What am I doing wrong? My component renders without props.

This is what was is rendered:

```
<wvd-hello-world msg="Hello World, coming to you from a Vue 3 component" data-v-app=""><div><h1 class="green"></h1></div></wvd-hello-world>
```

Comment: ` am trying to integrate Vue 3 with our CMS, which also has a Vue 2.6 project running side by side.` how exactly is that done ? fyi mounting to the vue app to the same div wont work iirc

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
defineProps<{
  msg?: string
}>()
```

Because

```
defineProps<{
  msg: string
}>()
```

means `$props.msg` should be `string` (`undefined` is not allowed).

```
createApp(HelloWorld).mount("wvd-hello-world");
```

means to **render `<HelloWorld />`** to `<wvd-hello-world>` in entry HTML file (`index.html`).

As you can see, `<HelloWorld>` doesn't receive prop `msg`, that means `$props.msg` is `undefined` but it is not allowed.